# Not working query in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g

Have a look on query ...Only email is string rest all are double .

```
 public int addSalary(Salary s,int empid) {
    int vount=0;
    try{
       vount=st.executeUpdate("insert into salary values("+s.getEmpid()+","+s.getAcc_no()+","+s.getBasicSalary()+",'"+s.getEmail()+"',"+s.getPFA()+","+s.getTaxes()+","+s.getBonus()+","+s.getNoOfLeaves()+","+s.getWorked_Days()+")");
       System.out.println(vount);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return vount;
}
```

Comment: You can do better than - 'not working'. what is the exception, what is the structure of your salary table, what are the values you are inserting.... also this looks like java, so you should add java tag ...

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: As others have pointed out, this is going to be closed without more data.  My first blush is that you should be using bind variables.  If you were going to write code that was intentionally open to SQL injection, you'd have to at least surround things that are supposed to be strings in single quotes (and escape any single quotes in the strings themselves).